# WPF Grid content not spanning the full width

Tags: wpf, xaml, binding

**SUMMARY**

To make it clearer for future readers, here is a summary of the problem and its fix.

My grid sits in a page, that is used as the content for a tabitem. At runtime, the grid refused to fill the entire tabitem area, as seen in the screenshots below.

The problem was that the style for the tabitem contained a content template that displayed the page through a contentpresenter, *inside* a horizontal stackpanel. The stackpanel was overriding the stretch properties of the grid in the page.

***The solution*** was to replace the stackpanel in the style with a grid. No more layout problems.

**ORIGINAL QUESTION**

I've got a StackPanel with a label and textbox inside a Grid, and I want to bind the width of the textbox to the width of the first two columns in the grid. I've generally been using the approach of binding the textbox width to its parent, and trying to bind *that* value to **something** that  has the correct value, but I have tried direct binding as well, and no luck.

Here is my xaml:

```
<Page x:Class="BPC.CPI.Pages.CustomerMaintenance"
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
  xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
  xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
  xmlns:cpihelpers="clr-namespace:BPC.CPI.ControlHelpers"
  xmlns:robertData="clr-namespace:BPC.Robert.DataEncapsulation;assembly=BPC.Robert"
  xmlns:robertGlobals="clr-namespace:BPC.Robert.Globals;assembly=BPC.Robert"
  xmlns:avalon="clr-namespace:AvalonLambdas;assembly=AvalonLambdas"
  xmlns:converters="clr-namespace:BPC.Utilities.ValueConverters;assembly=BPCUtilities"
  mc:Ignorable="d" 
  d:DesignHeight="602" d:DesignWidth="1149"
  Title="CustomerMaintenance" Name="ThisPage"
  DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
<Page.Resources>
    <converters:IntegerToBooleanConverter x:Key="IntegerToBooleanConverter"></converters:IntegerToBooleanConverter>
</Page.Resources>

<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid Grid.Row="0">
        <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding PageModel.PageUser.AssociatedCustomers}" Name="CbCustomerName" 
                  SelectedItem="{Binding PageModel.PageCustomer}"
                  Style="{StaticResource HeadingTwoComboBox}" cpihelpers:ComboBoxHelper.MaxDropDownItems="10">
            <ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="ComboBoxItem">
                    <Setter Property="LayoutTransform" Value="{StaticResource Transform.5x}"></Setter>
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black"></Setter>
                </Style>
            </ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        </ComboBox>
    </Grid>
    <Grid Name="GridMainContent" Grid.Row="1">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="20"></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid Name="GridGeneralCustomerInfo" Grid.Column="0" >
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="5"></RowDefinition>
                <RowDefinition Height=".35*"></RowDefinition>
                <RowDefinition Height="1*"></RowDefinition>
                <RowDefinition Height=".8*"></RowDefinition>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <StackPanel Name="SpCustomerNotes" Orientation="Vertical" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1"
                        HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                <Label Name="LblCustomerNotes" Target="{Binding ElementName=TxtCustomerNotes}" Style="{StaticResource PromptText}" Content="{Binding Path=Text, ElementName=CbCustomerName}" ContentStringFormat="What is special about {0}?"></Label>
                <TextBox Name="TxtCustomerNotes" AcceptsReturn="True" TextWrapping="Wrap" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                         MaxHeight="{Binding Path=ActualHeight, ElementName=SpCustomerNotes, Converter={avalon:LambdaValueConverter (param * 0.65)}}"
                         Text="{Binding PageModel.PageCustomer.CustomerInfo.CP_NOTES}"></TextBox>
            </StackPanel>
            <Grid Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource HeadingFourBrown}" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Text="{Binding Path=Text, ElementName=CbCustomerName, StringFormat=A few questions about \{0\}...}"></TextBlock>
                <StackPanel Name="SpReportingType" Orientation="Vertical" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Margin="6,0,0,0">
                    <Label Name="LblReportingType" Target="{Binding ElementName=TxtReportingType}" Style="{StaticResource PromptText}" Content="Contractual or actual reporting?"></Label>
                    <ComboBox Name="CbReportingType" Style="{StaticResource ComboBoxWithoutBackground}" SelectedValuePath="REPORTING_TYPE_ID"
                              ItemsSource="{Binding PageModel.PageSelection.ReportingTypes}" DisplayMemberPath="NAME"
                              SelectedValue="{Binding PageModel.PageCustomer.CustomerInfo.REPORTING_TYPE_ID}"></ComboBox>
                </StackPanel>
                <StackPanel Name="SpReportingLevel" Orientation="Vertical" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Margin="6,0,0,0">
                    <Label Name="LblReportingLevel" Target="{Binding ElementName=TxtReportingLevel}" Style="{StaticResource PromptText}" Content="How should we roll up data?"></Label>
                    <ComboBox Name="CbReportingLevel" Style="{StaticResource ComboBoxWithoutBackground}" SelectedValuePath="REPORTING_LEVEL_ID"
                              ItemsSource="{Binding PageModel.PageSelection.ReportingLevel}" DisplayMemberPath="NAME"
                              SelectedValue="{Binding PageModel.PageCustomer.CustomerInfo.REPORTING_LEVEL_ID}"></ComboBox>
                </StackPanel>
                <StackPanel Name="SpReportingPounds" Orientation="Vertical" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0" Margin="6,0,0,0">
                    <Label Name="LblReportingPounds" Target="{Binding ElementName=TxtReportingPounds}" Style="{StaticResource PromptText}" Content="Net or gross weights?"></Label>
                    <ComboBox Name="CbReportingPounds" Style="{StaticResource ComboBoxWithoutBackground}" SelectedValuePath="REPORTING_LBS_ID"
                              ItemsSource="{Binding PageModel.PageSelection.ReportingPounds}" DisplayMemberPath="NAME"
                              SelectedValue="{Binding PageModel.PageCustomer.CustomerInfo.REPORTING_LBS_ID}"></ComboBox>
                </StackPanel>
                <StackPanel Name="SpInventoryLevel" Orientation="Vertical" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Margin="6,0,0,0">
                    <Label Name="LblInventoryLevel" Target="{Binding ElementName=TxtInventoryLevel}" Style="{StaticResource PromptText}" Content="Customer or title?"></Label>
                    <ComboBox Name="CbInventoryLevel" Style="{StaticResource ComboBoxWithoutBackground}" SelectedValuePath="INV_RPT_LEVEL_ID"
                              ItemsSource="{Binding PageModel.PageSelection.InventoryReportingLevel}" DisplayMemberPath="NAME"
                              SelectedValue="{Binding PageModel.PageCustomer.CustomerInfo.INV_RPT_LEVEL_ID}"></ComboBox>
                </StackPanel>
                <StackPanel Name="SpReportByPO" Orientation="Vertical" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Margin="6,0,0,0">
                    <Label Name="LblReportByPO" Target="{Binding ElementName=TxtReportByPO}" Style="{StaticResource PromptText}" Content="Do we report by PO?"></Label>
                    <CheckBox Name="ChkReportByPO" Style="{DynamicResource SliderCheckBox}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Checked="ChkReportByPO_Checked"
                              IsChecked="{Binding PageModel.PageCustomer.CustomerInfo.IS_REPORTED_BY_PO, Converter={StaticResource IntegerToBooleanConverter}}"></CheckBox>
                </StackPanel>
            </Grid>
            <Grid Name="GridMiscellaneous" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="3">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
                    <RowDefinition Height="5"></RowDefinition>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
                    <RowDefinition Height="5"></RowDefinition>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource HeadingFourBrown}" Grid.Row="0" Text="Other stuff"></TextBlock>
                <StackPanel Name="SpSaveDirectory" Orientation="Vertical" Grid.Row="1" Margin="6,0,0,0">
                    <Label Name="LblSaveDirectory" Target="{Binding ElementName=TxtSaveDirectory}" Style="{StaticResource PromptText}" Content="Where should saved reports go?"></Label>
                    <TextBox Name="TxtSaveDirectory" ></TextBox>
                </StackPanel>
                <StackPanel Name="SpFrequency" Orientation="Vertical" Grid.Row="3" Margin="6,0,0,0">
                    <Label Name="LblFrequency" Target="{Binding ElementName=TxtFrequency}" Style="{StaticResource PromptText}" Content="{Binding Path=Text, ElementName=CbCustomerName}" ContentStringFormat="How often do you run reports for {0}?"></Label>
                    <TextBox Name="TxtFrequency" ></TextBox>
                </StackPanel>
                <StackPanel Name="SpHoursPerReport" Orientation="Vertical" Grid.Row="5" Margin="6,0,0,0">
                    <Label Name="LblHoursPerReport" Target="{Binding ElementName=TxtHoursPerReport}" Style="{StaticResource PromptText}" Content="How many hours do you spend per report (whole hours)?"></Label>
                    <TextBox Name="TxtHoursPerReport" ></TextBox>
                </StackPanel>
            </Grid>
        </Grid>
        <Grid Name="GridCustomerPeopleAndTitles" Grid.Column="2">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="1.2*"></RowDefinition>
                <RowDefinition Height="1.5*"></RowDefinition>
                <RowDefinition Height=".8*"></RowDefinition>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid Name="GridCustomerPeople" Grid.Row="0">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <TextBlock Name="TxtbCustomerPeople" Grid.Row="0" Style="{StaticResource HeadingFourBrown}" Text="{Binding Path=Text, ElementName=CbCustomerName, StringFormat=These people also work with \{0\}}"></TextBlock>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Grid.Row="1" Margin="6,0,0,0">
                    <Label Name="LblSalesReps" Style="{StaticResource PromptText}" Content="Sales Reps:"></Label>
                    <TextBlock Name="TxtbSalesReps" Text="{Binding PageModel.PageCustomer.SalesReps}" TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis" MaxWidth="550"></TextBlock>
                </StackPanel>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Grid.Row="2" Margin="6,0,0,0">
                    <Label Name="LblBillers" Style="{StaticResource PromptText}" Content="Billers:"></Label>
                    <TextBlock Name="TxtbBillers" Text="{Binding PageModel.PageCustomer.Billers}" TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis" MaxWidth="550"></TextBlock>
                </StackPanel>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Grid.Row="3" Margin="6,0,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                    <Label Name="LblCams" Style="{StaticResource PromptText}" Content="Customer Account Managers:"></Label>
                    <TextBlock Name="TxtbCams" Text="{Binding PageModel.PageCustomer.CAMs}" TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis"></TextBlock>
                </StackPanel>
            </Grid>
            <Grid Name="GridTitleGroups" Grid.Row="1">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <TextBlock Name="TxtbTitleGroups" Grid.Row="0" Style="{StaticResource HeadingFourBrown}" Text="{Binding Path=Text, ElementName=CbCustomerName, StringFormat=Group \{0\}\'s titles}"></TextBlock>
                <Grid Grid.Row="1">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="15"></ColumnDefinition>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="10"></ColumnDefinition>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="15"></ColumnDefinition>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ListBox Name="ListTitles" ItemsSource="{Binding}" Grid.Column="1" ToolTip="{Binding Source={x:Static robertGlobals:Messages.DragTitles}}">

                    </ListBox>
                    <Border Grid.Column="3" Style="{StaticResource BlueBorder}">
                        <Grid Name="GridTitleGroupItems" Grid.Column="3">
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="30"></RowDefinition>
                            <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <Rectangle Grid.Row="0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Fill="{StaticResource BrownAccentBrush}" OpacityMask="{StaticResource StrongOpacityMaskBrush}"
                                       ToolTip="{Binding Source={x:Static robertGlobals:Messages.DragTitlesNew}}"></Rectangle>
                            <TextBlock Name="TxtbNewTitleGroup" Grid.Row="0" Text="Create a New Group" AllowDrop="True" HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                 VerticalAlignment="Center" Style="{StaticResource GreenAccentText}" ToolTip="{Binding Source={x:Static robertGlobals:Messages.DragTitlesNew}}"></TextBlock>
                            <TreeView Name="TreeTitleGroups" ItemsSource="{Binding}" AllowDrop="True" Grid.Row="1" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" ToolTip="{Binding Source={x:Static robertGlobals:Messages.DragTitles}}">

                        </TreeView>
                    </Grid>
                    </Border>
                </Grid>
            </Grid>
            <Grid Name="GridCustomerGroups" Grid.Row="2">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <TextBlock Name="TxtbCustomerGroups" Grid.Row="0" Style="{StaticResource HeadingFourBrown}" Text="{Binding Path=Text, ElementName=CbCustomerName, StringFormat=Group \{0\}\'s customers}"></TextBlock>
            </Grid>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
</Page>
```

I've tried several recommended work-arounds from various questions and other sites, but nothing is working. I've tried sticking a border over cells I want to bind to and binding to its dimensions, using a label, nesting another grid, x:naming the ColumnDefinition and binding to the ActualWidth and more. Nothing. Works.

This seems like something that should be really simple in wpf, and I'm just missing come crucial, minor piece. I've wasted probably three hours on this. What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT:**

I just realized that it appears that I'm binding to the width of the entire GridMainContent - I'm not. That was just kind of dummy value that has been replaced with each different solution I've tried.

Here is an image of my issue. The contents should fill the entire tab. Note that the surrounding grid is sizing *down* to fit the content, rather than the content sizing *up* to fit the grid. I've defined implicit styles that set HorizontalAlignment=Stretch on every parent element for my content, but nothing appears to be working.

What I expect it to do, is for the left portion (with the dropdowns) and the right portion (with the sales reps & such) to be equal in width, filling the entire content area of the tab.

[image: whatitdoesbutshouldnt]

Comment: Just try avoiding binding, use WPF layout.

Comment: That's not acceptable. I need the widths to scale correctly with its parent width.

Comment: What's wrong with giving your grid children Grid.ColumnSpan = 4?

Comment: I need other elements to take up the remaining columns. Perhaps I misunderstand your question.

Comment: Could you update your XAML with the actual binding source?

Comment: The question, perhaps poorly worded, is what to bind to in order to get columns to honor the width I've defined for them. I've designed the grid such that it should have 4 equal-width columns, and I want the StackPanel to cover the first two columns. I expect it cover half the width of the grid, but instead it sizes to the width of its content (note that the stackpanel is oriented vertically). I don't know what I should bind it to. Currently, the temporary work-around is to hardcode the width, which is not okay, in the long run. I'll update the code to indicate my question.

Comment: Could you describe what's wrong with the layout and what it should be? Binding to size elements isn't great, they leave in two separate universes the layout and the binding.

Comment: I added an image and some description that I think should clear it up some. What you describe is precisely what I want - for the size of the columns to be decoupled from the size of the contents.

Comment: What would be of help is if you could publish up the entire view XAML, nevermind bindings. Stretch is a default value for both alignments so doesn't have to be specified.

Comment: My company's policy is not to use the View Model structure, but I'll put up the entire XAML. I have since redesigned the page to use more sub-grids and fewer column, but the problem remains the same.

Comment: I added the Page XAML. I can't add the resource dictionary I'm using - I blow right past the character limit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found what was causing the content to not size appropriately. Buried in the tab item style, the ContentTemplate was placing all the content inside a horizontal StackPanel. I switched the StackPanel for a Grid, and voila! Correct wpf layout.

Answer (score 1):

Try pasting the xaml below as WPF window content, don't use tabs- I've done that and the layout is fine:

Could you confirm is the layout is correct? My best bet is - the parent of the root grid somehow limiting the available space, so the available width is less the the screen's width. Check if all the available space is paint with lime.

XAML:

```
<Grid Background="Lime">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid Grid.Row="0">
            <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding PageModel.PageUser.AssociatedCustomers}" Name="CbCustomerName" 
                  SelectedItem="{Binding PageModel.PageCustomer}"
                  >
                <ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="ComboBoxItem">
                        <Setter Property="LayoutTransform" ></Setter>
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black"></Setter>
                    </Style>
                </ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
            </ComboBox>
        </Grid>
        <Grid Name="GridMainContent" Grid.Row="1">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="20"></ColumnDefinition>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid Name="GridGeneralCustomerInfo" Grid.Column="0" >
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="5"></RowDefinition>
                    <RowDefinition Height=".35*"></RowDefinition>
                    <RowDefinition Height="1*"></RowDefinition>
                    <RowDefinition Height=".8*"></RowDefinition>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <StackPanel Name="SpCustomerNotes" Orientation="Vertical" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1"
                        HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                    <Label Name="LblCustomerNotes" Target="{Binding ElementName=TxtCustomerNotes}" Content="{Binding Path=Text, ElementName=CbCustomerName}" ContentStringFormat="What is special about {0}?"></Label>
                    <TextBox Name="TxtCustomerNotes" AcceptsReturn="True" TextWrapping="Wrap" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                         Text="{Binding PageModel.PageCustomer.CustomerInfo.CP_NOTES}"></TextBox>
                </StackPanel>
                <Grid Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2">
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
                        <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
                        <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
                        <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Text="{Binding Path=Text, ElementName=CbCustomerName, StringFormat=A few questions about \{0\}...}"></TextBlock>
                    <StackPanel Name="SpReportingType" Orientation="Vertical" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Margin="6,0,0,0">
                        <Label Name="LblReportingType" Target="{Binding ElementName=TxtReportingType}" Content="Contractual or actual reporting?"></Label>
                        <ComboBox Name="CbReportingType" SelectedValuePath="REPORTING_TYPE_ID"
                              ItemsSource="{Binding PageModel.PageSelection.ReportingTypes}" DisplayMemberPath="NAME"
                              SelectedValue="{Binding PageModel.PageCustomer.CustomerInfo.REPORTING_TYPE_ID}"></ComboBox>
                    </StackPanel>
                    <StackPanel Name="SpReportingLevel" Orientation="Vertical" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Margin="6,0,0,0">
                        <Label Name="LblReportingLevel" Target="{Binding ElementName=TxtReportingLevel}" Content="How should we roll up data?"></Label>
                        <ComboBox Name="CbReportingLevel" SelectedValuePath="REPORTING_LEVEL_ID"
                              ItemsSource="{Binding PageModel.PageSelection.ReportingLevel}" DisplayMemberPath="NAME"
                              SelectedValue="{Binding PageModel.PageCustomer.CustomerInfo.REPORTING_LEVEL_ID}"></ComboBox>
                    </StackPanel>
                    <StackPanel Name="SpReportingPounds" Orientation="Vertical" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0" Margin="6,0,0,0">
                        <Label Name="LblReportingPounds" Target="{Binding ElementName=TxtReportingPounds}" Content="Net or gross weights?"></Label>
                        <ComboBox Name="CbReportingPounds" SelectedValuePath="REPORTING_LBS_ID"
                              ItemsSource="{Binding PageModel.PageSelection.ReportingPounds}" DisplayMemberPath="NAME"
                              SelectedValue="{Binding PageModel.PageCustomer.CustomerInfo.REPORTING_LBS_ID}"></ComboBox>
                    </StackPanel>
                    <StackPanel Name="SpInventoryLevel" Orientation="Vertical" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Margin="6,0,0,0">
                        <Label Name="LblInventoryLevel" Target="{Binding ElementName=TxtInventoryLevel}" Content="Customer or title?"></Label>
                        <ComboBox Name="CbInventoryLevel" SelectedValuePath="INV_RPT_LEVEL_ID"
                              ItemsSource="{Binding PageModel.PageSelection.InventoryReportingLevel}" DisplayMemberPath="NAME"
                              SelectedValue="{Binding PageModel.PageCustomer.CustomerInfo.INV_RPT_LEVEL_ID}"></ComboBox>
                    </StackPanel>
                    <StackPanel Name="SpReportByPo" Orientation="Vertical" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Margin="6,0,0,0">
                        <Label Name="LblReportByPo" Target="{Binding ElementName=TxtReportByPO}" Content="Do we report by PO?"></Label>
                        <CheckBox Name="ChkReportByPo" Style="{DynamicResource SliderCheckBox}" HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                              ></CheckBox>
                    </StackPanel>
                </Grid>
                <Grid Name="GridMiscellaneous" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="3">
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
                        <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
                        <RowDefinition Height="5"></RowDefinition>
                        <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
                        <RowDefinition Height="5"></RowDefinition>
                        <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Text="Other stuff"></TextBlock>
                    <StackPanel Name="SpSaveDirectory" Orientation="Vertical" Grid.Row="1" Margin="6,0,0,0">
                        <Label Name="LblSaveDirectory" Target="{Binding ElementName=TxtSaveDirectory}" Content="Where should saved reports go?"></Label>
                        <TextBox Name="TxtSaveDirectory" ></TextBox>
                    </StackPanel>
                    <StackPanel Name="SpFrequency" Orientation="Vertical" Grid.Row="3" Margin="6,0,0,0">
                        <Label Name="LblFrequency" Target="{Binding ElementName=TxtFrequency}"  Content="{Binding Path=Text, ElementName=CbCustomerName}" ContentStringFormat="How often do you run reports for {0}?"></Label>
                        <TextBox Name="TxtFrequency" ></TextBox>
                    </StackPanel>
                    <StackPanel Name="SpHoursPerReport" Orientation="Vertical" Grid.Row="5" Margin="6,0,0,0">
                        <Label Name="LblHoursPerReport" Target="{Binding ElementName=TxtHoursPerReport}" Content="How many hours do you spend per report (whole hours)?"></Label>
                        <TextBox Name="TxtHoursPerReport" ></TextBox>
                    </StackPanel>
                </Grid>
            </Grid>
            <Grid Name="GridCustomerPeopleAndTitles" Grid.Column="2">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="1.2*"></RowDefinition>
                    <RowDefinition Height="1.5*"></RowDefinition>
                    <RowDefinition Height=".8*"></RowDefinition>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Grid Name="GridCustomerPeople" Grid.Row="0">
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
                        <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
                        <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
                        <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <TextBlock Name="TxtbCustomerPeople" Grid.Row="0" Text="{Binding Path=Text, ElementName=CbCustomerName, StringFormat=These people also work with \{0\}}"></TextBlock>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Grid.Row="1" Margin="6,0,0,0">
                        <Label Name="LblSalesReps" Content="Sales Reps:"></Label>
                        <TextBlock Name="TxtbSalesReps" Text="{Binding PageModel.PageCustomer.SalesReps}" TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis" MaxWidth="550"></TextBlock>
                    </StackPanel>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Grid.Row="2" Margin="6,0,0,0">
                        <Label Name="LblBillers" Content="Billers:"></Label>
                        <TextBlock Name="TxtbBillers" Text="{Binding PageModel.PageCustomer.Billers}" TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis" MaxWidth="550"></TextBlock>
                    </StackPanel>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Grid.Row="3" Margin="6,0,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                        <Label Name="LblCams" Content="Customer Account Managers:"></Label>
                        <TextBlock Name="TxtbCams" Text="{Binding PageModel.PageCustomer.CAMs}" TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis"></TextBlock>
                    </StackPanel>
                </Grid>
                <Grid Name="GridTitleGroups" Grid.Row="1">
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
                        <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <TextBlock Name="TxtbTitleGroups" Grid.Row="0" Text="{Binding Path=Text, ElementName=CbCustomerName, StringFormat=Group \{0\}\'s titles}"></TextBlock>
                    <Grid Grid.Row="1">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="15"></ColumnDefinition>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="10"></ColumnDefinition>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="15"></ColumnDefinition>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ListBox Name="ListTitles" ItemsSource="{Binding}" Grid.Column="1" ToolTip="">

                        </ListBox>
                        <Border Grid.Column="3">
                            <Grid Name="GridTitleGroupItems">
                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="30"></RowDefinition>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <Rectangle Grid.Row="0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                                       ToolTip=""></Rectangle>
                                <TextBlock Name="TxtbNewTitleGroup" Grid.Row="0" Text="Create a New Group" AllowDrop="True" HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                 VerticalAlignment="Center" ToolTip=""></TextBlock>
                                <TreeView Name="TreeTitleGroups" ItemsSource="{Binding}" AllowDrop="True" Grid.Row="1" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" ToolTip="">

                                </TreeView>
                            </Grid>
                        </Border>
                    </Grid>
                </Grid>
                <Grid Name="GridCustomerGroups" Grid.Row="2">
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
                        <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <TextBlock Name="TxtbCustomerGroups" Grid.Row="0" Text="{Binding Path=Text, ElementName=CbCustomerName, StringFormat=Group \{0\}\'s customers}"></TextBlock>
                </Grid>
            </Grid>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
```

Comment: I've pasted the above code. The lime area unfortunately does **not** fill the entire available area. It stops right at the end of the dropdown. [pic here](http://i59.tinypic.com/2k30ib.png)

Comment: which proves the fact the the actual grid layout works. check out grid's parent - it must have its VerticalAlignment set to Left or it can be a custom panel which forces its child to occupy the smallest space possible.

Comment: I finally discovered the cause of the problem and corrected it, thanks to this answer ruling out problems with my local markup. A useful tactic for everyone, I think.